# Change Profile Display Upon Initial Login

Tags: php, administrator, login

I am using a membership extension to manage the users on my site along with the native Joomla login module. They sign up using the membership extension and the initial time that they login they are redirected to the native Joomla profile page (https://isls.encorelab.org/component/users/profile) which does not contain any of the information they had just entered when they signed up.

Everything is working fine for subsequent logins - they can only access the membership extension profile page (https://isls.encorelab.org/members/member-profile) which displays all of their information.

How do I make this initial login native Joomla profile never visible? Or make the initial login redirect to the extension profile page instead?

Comment: Hi megseoh. Welcome to JSE :) It might be easier for us to answer your question if we knew what membership extension you were using.

Comment: I'm using Membership Pro http://joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/membership-pro-joomla-membership-subscription.html

Answer (score 1):

What do they use for login ? The joomla login module, the com_users login form, or your membership's extension login ?

Joomla Login Module and com_users Login form, has settings for redirection after login. I don't know about your membership extension though.

But if you use any of the core joomla options, make sure you set up the after login redirections as per your will.

Note that, in order to manipulate com_users (User Manager) login form redirection, you need to create a menu item for the login form. In the menu items settings you can control the redirection.

Comment: I've tried changing the Joomla Module Login Redirection Page from 'Default' to my selected page but it's still going to the wrong page. Am I in the right place?

Comment: All depend on the entry (login) point. Are you using the joomla module for login?

Answer (score 1):

If the membership extension is already working and you already are using url rewrite, you could simply add a .htaccess rewrite rule. The benefit is that this would prevent people from accessing the profile page directly by simply writing it on the address bar.

Alternately you can do a template override on the Joomla com_users profile view that simply redirects it to the membership extensions member profile.